# how to run php file in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

i have created a file with extention .php.so how should i run this file with netbeans.i have download the netbeans 6.8 with all bundle feature.i hav seen the php file can run with netbeans so i m asking.plz explain

Answer (score -1):

[Run your project](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html#yurFirstPhpProject).
Make sure to [configure](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html) PHP in Netbeans.
If you don't have a php installation, check [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Comment: so you are to run an simple php program i should follow all the link and install whatever u have provided the link.no alternate method is there i have also wamp server.it cannot be used to do this

Comment: Any wamp server would do, provided that you configure your project correctly as described here: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html

Comment: i have followed the link but unable to download the file of xdebugger..i hav wino7 ultilate version and the file it support is not showing there.same is for apache Httpserver